# In NL do I need to pay back my salary if I'm leaving before end of month

Tags: netherlands, working, salary, contracts, labour-law

I just resigned from a company (first month) and unfortunately they have paid me a full salary already. How is it supposed to be handled? In previous companies, it was a risk we were ready to take but as it is a new one I would like to make sure I'm doing everything as per the law.

Thanks!

Comment: You should ask your employer, since they will know the details of your case. Normaly you are paid at the end of the month you worked. So it will be a matter of how many days in that month you didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

First, read your **employment contract**. It is unusual for employees to get paid in advance, so I assume this arrangement is laid out in the contract.

Now, whatever is not laid out in the contract falls back on Dutch labor law. There are two issues here:

1. The notice period. Dutch law [says](https://dutch.legal/index.php/2020/02/26/what-is-the-notice-period-in-the-netherlands-for-employee-and-employer/) (or see [the Google-Translation of the actual law](https://www-rijksoverheid-nl.translate.goog/onderwerpen/ontslag/vraag-en-antwoord/ontslag-nemen-opzegtermijn-werknemer?_x_tr_sl=auto&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=en-US&_x_tr_pto=wapp) that you need to give one month's notice when resigning, but no notice during the probationary period - which I would guess you were in (although, again, the contract may say otherwise). Failure to give notice often entitles the unnotified party to compensation of some kind.
2. The basic principle of payment for service rendered. If you work for N days you should get paid for N days (assuming notice requirements were satisfied). I'm guessing this is true in Dutch law as well although I am not well-versed in it.

Speaking of notice period - did you resign and stop showing up immediately, or have you only announced you're resigning? In the latter case, you may not want to stop showing up immediately.

After having prepared and read up, then do as @MarkJohnson suggested, which is talk to your employer. But let *them* say what they expect should happen, first, before responding.